# Apache Struts 2 Remote Code Execution(RCE) Flaw

Tags: security, struts2, ognl

As per the [link](https://www.zdnet.com/article/critical-remote-code-execution-flaw-in-apache-struts-exposes-the-enterprise-to-attack/)
struts 2 is vulnerable, & Users of Struts 2.3 are advised to upgrade to 2.3.35; users of Struts 2.5 need to upgrade to upgrade to 2.5.17.

I am using struts 2.3 version & latest releases only contain fixes for the vulnerability, backward compatibility isn't guaranteed.

Please suggest what  other alternative should I follow?

Comment: Apply the fix yourself? Don't set `alwaysSelectFullNamespace`? What do you mean by "backward compatibility isn't guaranteed"? If you're on the 2.3 branch then upgrading to the latest 2.3 version *shouldn't* expose any issues, but as with *any* changes, you should run it through your normal test suite. In the article you link to it states explicitly that the bump to 2.3.35 is *only* a fix for this vulnerability.

Comment: Release notes of 2.3.35 (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Version+Notes+2.3.35) confirms this version only fixes these issues. If you're on 2.3 branch you should have no problem upgrading to 2.3.35

Answer (score 0):

Do one or more of the following (1 and 3 are mutex)
1- Upgrade fully and regression test
2- Implement security manager policies to block FilePermission execute
3- If you have issues upgrading all of Struts try just upgrading the ognl jar. The Struts team will usually strengthen the OGNL sandbox after these issues.

This being said both 1 and 2 are your best bets. Make your security manager policies as tight as possible.